# How to add primary key constraint on two columns to make composite key in oracle?

Tags: composite-key

I am new to here, please help me to find an answer to the below query.

"How to add a primary key constraint on two columns to make a composite key column in a table?"

Instead of writing so many lines, kindly provide the answer as short as possible with code.

(I am creating a table in which I can have only one primary key on the values of two-columns as a composite key.)

JacknJill

Comment: Welcome, as a new contributor, you shouldn't request for solutions without having you tried first to solve the problem and then ask for help if you struggle at some point a can't advance. Please review your question a repost.

Answer (score 0):

You can create such constraint in scope of [CREATE TABLE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp) operator

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(25),
  bar VARCHAR(255),
  CONSTRAINT foo_pk PRIMARY KEY (id,name)
);
```

or [ALTER TABLE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_add_constraint.asp) operator

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(25),
  bar VARCHAR(255)
);
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT foo_pk PRIMARY KEY (id,name);
```